# How to split each element of a string array into different categories?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string

I am using node.js to fetch data from a website. Once I have that fetched data I want to insert into a mySQL database. Fetching the the url gives me a json dump of information.

After formatting the string, I am using an array to store my data. Below is an example of my output:

```
['table_id: 0xFC (252) SCTE 35',
  "section_syntax_indicator: '0'",
  "private_indicator: '0'",
  "reserved: '11'",
  'section_length: 0x39 (57)',
  'protocol_version: 0',
  'encrypted_packet: 0 no part of this message is encrypted',
  'encryption_algorithm: 0 No encryption',
  'pts_adjustment: 0xFFFF7F18 (33000) > Time: 95443.4 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 26:30:43.351',
  'cw_index: 0x00 (0)',
  'tier: 0x0FFF (4095)',
  'splice_command_length: 0x0005 (5)',
  'splice_command_type: 0x06 (6) time_signal [] time_signal: > Time: 19345 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 05:22:24.972',
  'time_specified_flag: 1 presence of the pts_time field',
  'reserved: 0x3F (63)',
  'pts_time: PTS: 1741047514 [0x67C646DA] > Time: 19345 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 05:22:24.972',
  'descriptor_loop_length: 35 [] Descriptors: [] segmentation_descriptor (0x02): Content Identification (0x01)',
  'descriptor_tag: 0x02 (2)',
  'descriptor_length: 0x21 (33)',
  'identifier: 0x43554549 (CUEI)',
  'segmentation_event_id: 0x00000001 (1)',
  "segmentation_event_cancel_indicator: '0' a previously sent segmentation event, identified by segmentation_event_id, has NOT been cancelled",
  'reserved: 0x7F (127)',
  "program_segmentation_flag: '1' the message refers to a Program Segmentation Point and that the mode is the Program Segmentation Mode whereby all PIDs/components of the program are to be segmented",
  "segmentation_duration_flag: '0' No presence of segmentation_duration field",
  "delivery_not_restricted_flag: '1' the next five bits are reserved",
  'reserved: 0x1F (31)',
  'segmentation_upid_type: 0x01 (1) Deprecated: use type 0x0C; The segmentation_upid does not follow a standard naming scheme.',
  'segmentation_upid_length: 0x12 (18)',
  'segmentation_type_id: 0x01 (1) Content Identification',
  'segment_num: 0x01 (1)',
  'segments_expected: 0x01 (1)',
  'CRC_32: 0x46D15AF3 CRC OK'
]
```

I want to split each element of this array into different categories.

For example: `"time_specified_flag: 1 presence of the pts_time field"`

I want this element into 3 different categories (parameter, value, description). Like `[time_specified_flag, 1, presence of the pts_time field]`

Edit: this is the original json dump as a string: `"dump" : "======================================================================================================================================\r\n| PID: 0401 [SEC -> SCTE-35]   length: 60[0x003C]   status: VALID |\r\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\nAddress     Parameter                                                              Length    Value                 Description\r\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n<span class=\"hex_tree_child\">0x0000,0:  [-] PID: 0401 [SEC -> SCTE-35]                                          <0x2A,0> :                       (37 nodes in 3 levels)</span>\r\n0x0000,0:       * table_id                                                         <0x1,0> : 0xFC (252)            SCTE 35\r\n0x0001,0:       * section_syntax_indicator                                         <0x0,1> : '0'\r\n0x0001,1:       * private_indicator                                                <0x0,1> : '0'\r\n0x0001,2:       * reserved                                                         <0x0,2> : '11'\r\n0x0001,4:       * section_length                                                   <0x1,4> : 0x39 (57)\r\n0x0003,0:       * protocol_version                                                 <0x1,0> : 0\r\n0x0004,0:       * encrypted_packet                                                 <0x0,1> : 0                     no part of this message is encrypted\r\n0x0004,1:       * encryption_algorithm                                             <0x0,6> : 0                     No encryption\r\n0x0004,7:       * pts_adjustment                                                   <0x4,1> : 0xFFFF7F18 (-33000)   => Time: 95443.4 sec => (hh:mm:ss.ms) 26:30:43.351\r\n0x0009,0:       * cw_index                                                         <0x1,0> : 0x00 (0)\r\n0x000A,0:       * tier                                                             <0x1,4> : 0x0FFF (4095)\r\n0x000B,4:       * splice_command_length                                            <0x1,4> : 0x0005 (5)\r\n0x000D,0:       * splice_command_type                                              <0x1,0> : 0x06 (6)              time_signal\r\n<span class=\"hex_tree_child\">0x000E,0:      [-] time_signal                                                     <0x5,0> :                       => Time: 19345 sec => (hh:mm:ss.ms) 05:22:24.972</span>\r\n0x000E,0:           * time_specified_flag                                          <0x0,1> : 1                     presence of the pts_time field\r\n0x000E,1:           * reserved                                                     <0x0,6> : 0x3F (63)\r\n0x000E,7:           * pts_time                                                     <0x4,1> : PTS: 1741047514 [0x67C646DA]  => Time: 19345 sec => (hh:mm:ss.ms) 05:22:24.972\r\n0x0013,0:       * descriptor_loop_length                                           <0x2,0> : 35\r\n<span class=\"hex_tree_child\">0x0015,0:      [-] Descriptors                                                     <0x11,0> :</span>\r\n<span class=\"hex_tree_child\">0x0015,0:          [-] segmentation_descriptor (0x02)                              <0x11,0> :                       Content Identification (0x01)</span>\r\n0x0015,0:               * descriptor_tag                                           <0x1,0> : 0x02 (2)\r\n0x0016,0:               * descriptor_length                                        <0x1,0> : 0x21 (33)\r\n0x0017,0:               * identifier                                               <0x4,0> : 0x43554549 (CUEI)\r\n0x001B,0:               * segmentation_event_id                                    <0x4,0> : 0x00000001 (1)\r\n0x001F,0:               * segmentation_event_cancel_indicator                      <0x0,1> : '0'                   a previously sent segmentation event, identified by segmentation_event_id, has NOT been cancelled\r\n0x001F,1:               * reserved                                                 <0x0,7> : 0x7F (127)\r\n0x0020,0:               * program_segmentation_flag                                <0x0,1> : '1'                   the message refers to a Program Segmentation Point and that the mode is the Program Segmentation Mode whereby all PIDs/components of the program are to be segmented\r\n0x0020,1:               * segmentation_duration_flag                               <0x0,1> : '0'                   No presence of segmentation_duration field\r\n0x0020,2:               * delivery_not_restricted_flag                             <0x0,1> : '1'                   the next five bits are reserved\r\n0x0020,3:               * reserved                                                 <0x0,5> : 0x1F (31)\r\n0x0021,0:               * segmentation_upid_type                                   <0x1,0> : 0x01 (1)              Deprecated: use type 0x0C; The segmentation_upid does not follow a standard naming scheme.\r\n0x0022,0:               * segmentation_upid_length                                 <0x1,0> : 0x12 (18)\r\n0x0035,0:               * segmentation_type_id                                     <0x1,0> : 0x01 (1)              Content Identification\r\n0x0036,0:               * segment_num                                              <0x1,0> : 0x01 (1)\r\n0x0037,0:               * segments_expected                                        <0x1,0> : 0x01 (1)\r\n0x0038,0:       * CRC_32                                                           <0x4,0> : 0x46D15AF3            CRC OK\r\n======================================================================================================================================\r\n",`

Here is my code snippet to format this blob of data:

[My code to format the JSON response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4968.png)

Is this something that is possible to do?

Comment: Can you share a small snippet of the JSON from the URL and also the code you've used to format it to this structure?

Comment: Everything is possible if you put in some effort. Could you share some code that you tried or a place where you're stuck.

Comment: The `map` function can handle this easily. Also, it might be easier to work with the original `json` structure. What does that look like?

Comment: @maazadeeb I updated the post.

Comment: Also, @ToddSkelton the JSON is a pain to look at. So I needed to format me to only grab the important things.

Comment: Gotcha, I didn't realize it was just one big string.

Comment: How do you want the ones that don't just have a number formatted? For example, what's the expected output for `'pts_time: PTS: 1741047514 [0x67C646DA] > Time: 19345 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 05:22:24.972'`

Comment: @ToddSkelton that one is interesting. `pts_time` would be the parameter, `PTS: 1741047514 [0x67C646DA]` would be the value and `> Time: 19345 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 05:22:24.972` would be the description.

Comment: @TayshawnHill ... was this already sufficient enough?... [version 1](https://regex101.com/r/alK9Q7/1) matches/captures exactly the `pts_time` like formats/categories whereas [version 2](https://regex101.com/r/alK9Q7/2) matches/captures the more generic formats/categories.

Comment: @PeterSeliger version 2 groups them how I would like them. However, I am not sure how to make use of the regex to put the parameter, value, and description into an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *@TayshawnHill ... was this already sufficient enough?... [version 1](https://regex101.com/r/alK9Q7/1) matches/captures exactly the `pts_time` like formats/categories whereas [version 2](https://regex101.com/r/alK9Q7/2) matches/captures the more generic formats/categories. – Peter Seliger*

> *@PeterSeliger version 2 groups them how I would like them. However, I am not sure how to make use of the regex to put the parameter, value, and description into an object. – Tayshawn Hill*

... here we go ...

```js
function createKeyValueAndDescriptionList(pattern) {
  const regXCompositeValue = (/^(?<key>[^:]+)\:\s*(?:(?<value>[A-Za-z]+\:\s*[^>]+))\s*(?<description>.*)/);
  const regXGenericValue = (/^(?<key>[^:]+):\s*(?<value>[\w']+(?:\s*\([^)]*\))*)\s*(?<description>.*)/);

  const { groups } = (
    regXCompositeValue.exec(pattern) ||
    regXGenericValue.exec(pattern) ||
    {}
  );
  return (groups && [

    groups.key,
    groups.value.trim(),
    groups.description || '',

  ] || []);
}

console.log([

  'table_id: 0xFC (252) SCTE 35',
  "section_syntax_indicator: '0'",
  "private_indicator: '0'",
  "reserved: '11'",
  'section_length: 0x39 (57)',
  'protocol_version: 0',
  'encrypted_packet: 0 no part of this message is encrypted',
  'encryption_algorithm: 0 No encryption',
  'pts_adjustment: 0xFFFF7F18 (33000) > Time: 95443.4 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 26:30:43.351',
  'cw_index: 0x00 (0)',
  'tier: 0x0FFF (4095)',
  'splice_command_length: 0x0005 (5)',
  'splice_command_type: 0x06 (6) time_signal [] time_signal: > Time: 19345 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 05:22:24.972',
  'time_specified_flag: 1 presence of the pts_time field',
  'reserved: 0x3F (63)',
  'pts_time: PTS: 1741047514 [0x67C646DA] > Time: 19345 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 05:22:24.972',
  'descriptor_loop_length: 35 [] Descriptors: [] segmentation_descriptor (0x02): Content Identification (0x01)',
  'descriptor_tag: 0x02 (2)',
  'descriptor_length: 0x21 (33)',
  'identifier: 0x43554549 (CUEI)',
  'segmentation_event_id: 0x00000001 (1)',
  "segmentation_event_cancel_indicator: '0' a previously sent segmentation event, identified by segmentation_event_id, has NOT been cancelled",
  'reserved: 0x7F (127)',
  "program_segmentation_flag: '1' the message refers to a Program Segmentation Point and that the mode is the Program Segmentation Mode whereby all PIDs/components of the program are to be segmented",
  "segmentation_duration_flag: '0' No presence of segmentation_duration field",
  "delivery_not_restricted_flag: '1' the next five bits are reserved",
  'reserved: 0x1F (31)',
  'segmentation_upid_type: 0x01 (1) Deprecated: use type 0x0C; The segmentation_upid does not follow a standard naming scheme.',
  'segmentation_upid_length: 0x12 (18)',
  'segmentation_type_id: 0x01 (1) Content Identification',
  'segment_num: 0x01 (1)',
  'segments_expected: 0x01 (1)',
  'CRC_32: 0x46D15AF3 CRC OK',

].map(createKeyValueAndDescriptionList));

console.log([

  "foo:------------",
  "bar:++++++++++++",
  "baz:############",

].map(createKeyValueAndDescriptionList));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @TayshawnHill ... I provided the still missing failure handling. The method fails silently with returning an empty array for each pattern that can not be matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
     function threeSplit(line){
       sep1= line.indexOf(": ")
       a = line.slice(0,sep1)
       line =line.slice(sep1+2)
       sep2 = line.indexOf(" ")
       b = line.slice(0,sep2)
       c=line.slice(sep2+1)
       return [a,b,c]  
    }



[
  'table_id: 0xFC (252) SCTE 35',
  "section_syntax_indicator: '0'",
  "private_indicator: '0'",
  "reserved: '11'",
   'section_length: 0x39 (57)',
 'protocol_version: 0',
 'encrypted_packet: 0 no part of this message is encrypted',
  'encryption_algorithm: 0 No encryption',
 'pts_adjustment: 0xFFFF7F18 (33000) > Time: 95443.4 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 26:30:43.351',
  'cw_index: 0x00 (0)',
  'tier: 0x0FFF (4095)',
  'splice_command_length: 0x0005 (5)',
  'splice_command_type: 0x06 (6) time_signal [] time_signal: > Time: 19345 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 05:22:24.972',
  'time_specified_flag: 1 presence of the pts_time field',
  'reserved: 0x3F (63)',
  'pts_time: PTS: 1741047514 [0x67C646DA] > Time: 19345 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 05:22:24.972',
 'descriptor_loop_length: 35 [] Descriptors: [] segmentation_descriptor (0x02): Content Identification (0x01)',
  'descriptor_tag: 0x02 (2)',
   'descriptor_length: 0x21 (33)',
   'identifier: 0x43554549 (CUEI)',
 'segmentation_event_id: 0x00000001 (1)',
  "segmentation_event_cancel_indicator: '0' a previously sent segmentation event, identified by segmentation_event_id, has NOT been cancelled",
  'reserved: 0x7F (127)',
   "program_segmentation_flag: '1' the message refers to a Program Segmentation Point and that the mode is the Program Segmentation Mode whereby all PIDs/components of the program are to be segmented",
   "segmentation_duration_flag: '0' No presence of segmentation_duration field",
   "delivery_not_restricted_flag: '1' the next five bits are reserved",
  'reserved: 0x1F (31)',
 'segmentation_upid_type: 0x01 (1) Deprecated: use type 0x0C; The segmentation_upid does not follow a standard naming scheme.',
   'segmentation_upid_length: 0x12 (18)',
   'segmentation_type_id: 0x01 (1) Content Identification',
 'segment_num: 0x01 (1)',
  'segments_expected: 0x01 (1)',
  'CRC_32: 0x46D15AF3 CRC OK'].map(threeSplit)

[
  [ 'table_id', '0xFC', '(252) SCTE 35' ],
  [ 'section_syntax_indicator', "'0", "'0'" ],
  [ 'private_indicator', "'0", "'0'" ],
  [ 'reserved', "'11", "'11'" ],
  [ 'section_length', '0x39', '(57)' ],
  [ 'protocol_version', '', '0' ],
  [ 'encrypted_packet', '0', 'no part of this message is encrypted' ],
  [ 'encryption_algorithm', '0', 'No encryption' ],
  [
    'pts_adjustment',
    '0xFFFF7F18',
    '(33000) > Time: 95443.4 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 26:30:43.351'
  ],
  [ 'cw_index', '0x00', '(0)' ],
  [ 'tier', '0x0FFF', '(4095)' ],
  [ 'splice_command_length', '0x0005', '(5)' ],
  [
    'splice_command_type',
    '0x06',
    '(6) time_signal [] time_signal: > Time: 19345 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 05:22:24.972'
  ],
  [ 'time_specified_flag', '1', 'presence of the pts_time field' ],
  [ 'reserved', '0x3F', '(63)' ],
  [
    'pts_time',
    'PTS:',
    '1741047514 [0x67C646DA] > Time: 19345 sec > (hh:mm:ss.ms) 05:22:24.972'
  ],
  [
    'descriptor_loop_length',
    '35',
    '[] Descriptors: [] segmentation_descriptor (0x02): Content Identification (0x01)'
  ],
  [ 'descriptor_tag', '0x02', '(2)' ],
  [ 'descriptor_length', '0x21', '(33)' ],
  [ 'identifier', '0x43554549', '(CUEI)' ],
  [ 'segmentation_event_id', '0x00000001', '(1)' ],
  [
    'segmentation_event_cancel_indicator',
    "'0'",
    'a previously sent segmentation event, identified by segmentation_event_id, has NOT been cancelled'
  ],
  [ 'reserved', '0x7F', '(127)' ],
  [
    'program_segmentation_flag',
    "'1'",
    'the message refers to a Program Segmentation Point and that the mode is the Program Segmentation Mode whereby all PIDs/components of the program are to be segmented'
  ],
  [
    'segmentation_duration_flag',
    "'0'",
    'No presence of segmentation_duration field'
  ],
  [
    'delivery_not_restricted_flag',
    "'1'",
    'the next five bits are reserved'
  ],
  [ 'reserved', '0x1F', '(31)' ],
  [
    'segmentation_upid_type',
    '0x01',
    '(1) Deprecated: use type 0x0C; The segmentation_upid does not follow a standard naming scheme.'
  ],
  [ 'segmentation_upid_length', '0x12', '(18)' ],
  [ 'segmentation_type_id', '0x01', '(1) Content Identification' ],
  [ 'segment_num', '0x01', '(1)' ],
  [ 'segments_expected', '0x01', '(1)' ],
  [ 'CRC_32', '0x46D15AF3', 'CRC OK' ]
]
`
```